# Smudged ink on visa sticker

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I got my EU visa yesterday, today I noticed it had smudged ink on the mrz . Can I travel with this or will they deny boarding me with this.

Ps: it is being detected by Android mrz reader

I don't know what airlines do in case they doubt forgery.

Please help.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the slightly darker spot around the number 14?

That is nothing, no need to worry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it's my first international trip so I was a bit scared.